# Determining if rounded numbers are a result of multiplication

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose I have 2 collections of lists.

In the first collection the lists consists of random integers, with most (but not all) in the range 0-1000.
In the second collection the lists consists of integers calculated in the following way:

a. start with a random integer of similar range to the first list

b. multiply by some unknown fraction, typically (but not always) in the range 0-2.

c. round to the nearest integer

Given a particular list, I would like to be able to predict which collection it comes from.

I have tried taking the modulo from every number between 2-20 and looking at the remainder (as for example if the fraction in b) was exactly 2, then the elements mod 2 would always be zero), but couldn't find a noticeable difference.  Would appreciate any ideas.

Comment: You don't say how long the lists are, but if they are not *too* short, the average of the elements of the first list would be around $500$, while the average of the elements of the second list would be around $500q$, where $q$ is the unknown number (likely) between $0$ and $2$. If $q$ is very close to $1$ you will never be able to tell the difference, but it is way off, you most likely will.

Comment: In fact, you can set the hypotheses: $H_0: q=1$ vs. $H_1: q\ne 1$ and use the machinery of [Statistical hypotheses testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) to accept or reject $H_0$ at certain significance (say $5\%$),

Comment: Does the multiplicative fraction in (b) vary or is it fixed for the whole list?  The range of  the rounded products is likely to be different in the two lists unless you are using a fixed fraction near $1$